# On some matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have as symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ such that
\begin{align}
0 \preceq A \preceq ( C+ D)^{-1}
\end{align}
where $C$ and $D$ are both symetric positive definite.

My question does there exists a matrix $B$ such that 
\begin{align}
A= ( B+ D)^{-1}
\end{align}

In the scalar case, this is trivial. If we have that
\begin{align}
0 \le a \le \frac{1}{c+d}
\end{align}
then we can always find some $ b \ge c$ such that
\begin{align}
a=\frac{1}{b+d}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar case generalises to the matrix case. Note that $A=(B+D)^{-1}$ iff $B=A^{-1}-D$. Since $(C+D)^{-1}\succeq A\succ0$, we have $A^{-1}\succeq C+D\succ0$ and hence $B=A^{-1}-D\succeq C\succ0$.